# How to make some Virtual IP Address?

Tags: wireless, networking, ip

I want to make some Virtual IP Addresses for my network adapter or wireless adapter, so that I can connect to network with more than one IP address from one computer or laptop.

How can I do it? (I know it's possible ,because one of my friends has done it in university and have more than one - some times till 255 - IP address in network).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual MAC address? I think you mean "virtual IP addresses". See `man 5 interfaces`, and follow the documentation links at the very end. On my system, it says:

> For  advice  on  configuring  this  package  read  the  Network  Configuration chapter of the Debian Reference manual, available at http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html or in the `debian-reference-en` package.
>
> Examples of how to set up interfaces can be found in `/usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples/network-interfaces.gz`.

But, even if you assign extra IP addresses, your traffic is still going in/out of your system through the SAME NIC. No matter how many IPs, only 1 NIC. No speedup. Multiple IP addresses are good for obfuscation, virtual machines, and simulated network testing.

Read and enjoy!